# How to increase Current in DC Adapter

Tags: current, dc, adapter

I have an AC-DC adapter with 500mA (it was a mistake when I bought it). It has a switch to reverse the polarity and a potentiometer where voltage can be adjusted from 1.5V (min) to 12V (max). Now what I need is a 2A or 1A current. Now, what modification needs to be done to get the same current at 12V?

When I opened the adapter, I was able to see a pot for changing voltage. Second a small circuit where 4 diodes are connected (which converts AC to DC) with a capacitor, a big square shape resistor (if am not wrong) which is connected to the pot.

How do I hack the circuit so I can achieve the required current with adjustable voltage?

Comment: You realize if you screw it up, you could set your house on fire right? Mains connected power supplies are not trivial things. You'd be better off just buying the right one.

Comment: The current rating of an AC-DC adapter is based on *all* of its components, starting with the transformer. To increase its current rating, you would need to evaluate every component and potentially replace it with a higher-rated one. It would be much safer (and probably cheaper) to source [an appropriate supply](http://www.allelectronics.com/make-a-store/item/PS-1227/12-VDC-2A-SWITCHING-POWER-SUPPLY/1.html).

Comment: *"I have a 1 liter pitcher, but I need it to hold 2 liters, how do I modify it for that?"*

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: You can't and shouldn't try.  Get the right power supply.

Small and cheap power supplies are built in high volume and optimized for the lowest cost to just meet the specs.  In some cases with less reputable manufacturers, they don't even meet their own specs.  If your power supply contains the component to support 1 A of output current, they would have sold it as a 1 A supply because they could have charged more money for that.  By the time you "modify" this supply to support 1 A, you will have essentially built your own supply.

Judging from the level of electronics understanding exhibited by your question, you also shouldn't be messing with anything connected directly to the power line.  You could make the whole supply unsafe so that you kill yourself some time later.  Worse, you could set your neighborhood on fire.